# Springfox tags not working on PagingAndSortingRepository

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, spring-rest, springfox

I'm using Spring Boot 1.5.8 with Springfox 2.8.0.  I'm adding a tag to my PagingAndSortingRepository in an attempt to organize all the crud methods under a "Subject Operations" heading in the Swagger UI.

However, the end result is that some of the methods show up under a **Subject Entity: Simple Jpa Repository** heading, e.g.

GET /api/subjects/{id}/images subjectImages

POST /api/subjects/{id}/images subjectImages

...and so on

and the remaining methods are under **Subject Operations:**

GET /api/subjects findAllSubject

POST /api/subjects saveSubject

..and so on.

It seems like the methods being generated by Spring for the foreign-key related data, e.g. /subjects/images, are not being moved under the tag but I'm not sure how to rectify this situation?

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "subjects", path = "subjects", excerptProjection = SubjectView.class)
@Api(tags = { "Subject Operations" })
public interface SubjectRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Subject, Integer> {

    @Query("select distinct s from Subject s "
        + "join s.images si "
        + "where si.dataset.id = ?1")
    Page<Subject> findByDatasetId(Pageable pagable, @Param("datasetId") int datasetId);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define tag in repository, then creates it in swagger configuration. Name of the tag is as standard tag "* Entity". This works for me:

```
@Api(tags = "Channel Entity")
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface ChannelRepository extends JpaRepository<Channel, Long> {
..
}
```

Swagger configuration:

```
 @Bean
  public Docket api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
        .apiInfo(apiInfo()).select()
        .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
        .paths(..))
        .build()
        .tags(new Tag("Channel Entity", "Data-rest endpoints"))
}
```